# How to develop gif like image in lightning component using sprites?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I want to use a down arraow, which is jumping continuously to prompt user to click on it. I want it something like a spinner which is by default spinning when we include it in code. So for the `lightning:icon` of type `utility:arrowdown` how can we give animation to it and make it jump or animate in some kind? It is afterall a sprite image and we must be able to toggle its size or something...but I am not getting how exactly can we do this. Anybody got any idea?

Comment: I think you should try CSS. You can do really complex stuff with it.